# Invoking an array of functions asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, arguments

I would like to invoke an array of functions asynchronously so that only once func1 has resolved, will func2 be invoked.

```js
function myAsyncFunction(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const func1 = () => myAsyncFunction('a');
const func2 = () => myAsyncFunction('b');
const func3 = () => myAsyncFunction('c');

function asychFunctions(arguments) {
  arguments.forEach(func => {
    func();
  });
}

asychFunctions([func1, func2, func3])
```

Comment: you need to invoke function one by one?

Comment: "asynchronously so that only once func1 has resolved, will func2 be invoked" — That's the opposite of what asynchronously means!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `forEach` loop.

You need to put the logic to call the next function in the `then` handler for the previous one.

Create a variable to track which function you are dealing with. Then, whenver you want to call a function (i.e. at the start and when the previous one is done), increment that variable, see if there is a function at that index waiting to be called, then call it.

```
function asychFunctions(args) {
    var index = -1;

    function call_next_function() {
        index++;
        if (args[index]) {
            args[index]().then(call_next_function);
        }
    }

    call_next_function(); // At this point, the next function is the first function.
}
```

---

This is probably a bad idea. The advantage of async functions is that you can get on with other stuff while waiting for them. In most cases, this approach will just slow things down and it is better to run them simultaneously.

Comment: Nice, but `arguments` might not be the best variable name, and will cause an error in strict mode I think?

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg — Oh drat. I copy/pasted that directly from the question without noticing that it was defined as an argument name. I assumed the arguments object was being used!

Answer (score 0):

You can chain promises and return one after the other:

```js
function myAsyncFunction(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(url), 2000)
  })
}

const func1 = () => myAsyncFunction('a')
const func2 = () => myAsyncFunction('b')
const func3 = () => myAsyncFunction('c')

func1()
  .then(result1 => {
    console.log('result from func1:', result1)
    return func2()
  })
  .then(result2 => {
    console.log('result from func2:', result2)
    return func3()
  })
  .then(result3 => {
    console.log('result from func3:', result3)
    console.log('finished!')
  })
```